# How to include the end date in a DatePeriod?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get a Date range for all workdays this week. I have written the following code to do so.

#### Code

```
$begin = new DateTime('monday this week'); 2016-07-04
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify('next friday'); // 2016-07-08

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);



foreach($daterange as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

#### Output

- 2016-07-04
- 2016-07-05
- 2016-07-06
- 2016-07-07

In the output friday is missing. I can fix this by doing `$end->modify('next saturday')` but I was wondering why the last day of a `DatePeriod` is not included in the range.

Comment: You're asking two things. You've answered the first question, you either need to `modify('+1')` or to initialize `next saturday` to include the last day. Why isn't the last date included or why there isn't a flag like `DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE` to `INCLUDE_END_DATE`, I don't know...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The iterator seems to check the time as well as the date, it excludes the end element if the time in the endDate is less that or equal to the time in the start date.

So ensure the time of the end date is at least a second greater that that of the start date.

```
// this will default to a time of 00:00:00
$begin = new DateTime('monday this week'); //2016-07-04

$end = clone $begin;

// this will default to a time of 00:00:00    
$end->modify('next friday'); // 2016-07-08

$end->setTime(0,0,1);     // new line

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach($daterange as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The reasoning why the last day is left out. Still, its a stupid default.

Comment: I think it's a design decision. Since you don't want fractions in your days, then it always takes the lower limit.

Answer (score 18):

Try this code

```
<?php
$begin = new DateTime('2016-07-04');
$end = clone $begin;
$end->modify('next friday'); // 2016-07-08
$end->modify('+1 day');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: This guy know what is up

Answer (score 5):

In PHP 8.2 you can use `DatePeriod::INCLUDE_END_DATE` as constructor option!

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#dateperiod.constants.include-end-date